# Why is there no 'settings'icon in con definitions

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, settings, kivy-language

Such a popular icon as a gear wheel. Why isn't it in KivyMD? That is for example:

```
MDIconButton:
    icon: 'settings'
```

Instead of an icon, it's just a white square. If you enter `setting,tuning, gear`, the result is the same. What's the matter?

Comment: Odd, your code works fine for me. I am using kivyMD  v0.104.1. What version are you using?

Comment: My kivymd version os 0.104.2, and version kivy 2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Try using "cog". I don't know what it means but apparently that's the settings icon.

Answer (score 1):

Icon for gear icon in kivymd is  "cog-outline"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are about 6300 icons to choose from, so that list is too long to post here.

Two ways I've found to get the right names are:

- You can `ctrl-f` through this [github](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/icon_definitions.py) link.

Or

- Download [KivyMD](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD)
- Run the 'Kitchen Sink' demo
- Scroll down and click on 'MD Icons'
- Search for icon name by using the search bar

The second option allows you to search visually.

> In the strict sense, a "cog" is a tooth on a wheel. A cogwheel is any wheel with teeth. A gear is a cogwheel used mesh with another cogwheel. And a sprocket is a cogwheel that links to another cogwheel by means of a chain.

[This ELL link explains more](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/235386/what-is-the-difference-between-cog-and-gear)

I am not sure why the developers chose to create a Material Theme based off of Google and then rename Google's icons.